# Getting "No frame found" when using in_frame

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

For some reason when I use the code below, my script returns "No frame found", but when I use watir-webdriver's browser.frame(:xpath => '//*[@id="Main"]').img(:xpath => '//*[@id="STSearchImage2"]') it works just fine.

Snippet of in_frame code:

```
# Main frame
in_frame(:id => 'Main') do |main_frame|
...
    # # Scheduled Tasks image
    image(:searchandfilter_clients_image, :xpath => '//*[@id="STSearchImg2"]', :frame => main_frame)
...
end
```

Snippet of code used in step:

```
searchandfilter_clients_image_element.click
```

The line above returns the error.

The frame I'm trying to select is within a frameset near the root of the body of the page.  I don't have any issues selecting the frame without page-object.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the watir-webdriver you shown is correct? Is the `STSearchImg2` the id of the frame or the id of the image within the frame?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I messed up in the explanation. STSearchImg2 is the id of the image, Main is the id of the frame.

Comment: Can you create/share html that reproduces the problem? I was able to create an html page that worked with your page object - ie did not raise any errors regarding the missing frame.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by removing xpath locator inside the frame. I suggested you @JoshuaHomer to use id instead of xpath.
in_frame(:id => 'Main') do |main_frame|
...
    # # Scheduled Tasks image
    image(:searchandfilter_clients_image, :id => 'STSearchImg2', :frame => main_frame)
...
end

Comment: @JustinKo it seems like we could not use xpath inside the frame. If we use xpath inside the frame it search the xpath in the entire page instead of searching within the frame. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @NMKP, while your suggestion about using :id instead of :xpath is good, I do not believe it will solve this problem. The exception is with locating the frame, which would occur before trying to locate the element. As well, I made a quick test and XPath seems to work fine with only searching within the frame. If you want to create a question with html and page-object, we can see where the error is.